How can I get the names of model terms that involve the reference levels of Factors?
For example, given a formula of outcome ~ country*educ + age, where

levels(country) is c("Australia", "Bengal", "China")
levels(educ) is c("Grade school", "High school", "University")
age is Numeric

then the names of coef() would be:
countryBengal
countryChina
educHigh school
educUniversity
age
countryBengal:educHigh school
countryBengal:educUniversity
countryChina:educHigh school
countryChina:educUniversity

I want to get a vector that includes the missing names of the reference terms that are involved in interactions, which would add these to the above list:
countryAustralia:educGrade school
countryAustralia:educHigh school
countryAustralia:educUniversity
countryBengal:educGrade school
countryChina:educGrade school

How does R build these names in the first place? Is this something that is stored in model outputs already that I can simply grab?
Here is a reprex for a survival model for testing. Thank you!
# install.packages("survival")
library(survival)

data <- cancer  # `cancer` is a dataset that comes with the `survival` package

data$inst <-
    factor(data$inst,
           levels = c(1:33),
           labels = c(rep("Sites 01-10", 10),
                      rep("Sites 11-20", 10),
                      rep("Sites 20-33", 13)))

data$sex <-
    factor(data$sex,
           levels = 2:1,
           labels = c("Female", "Male"))

data$ph.ecog <-
    factor(data$ph.ecog,
           levels = 0:4,
           labels = c("Asymptomatic",
                      "Symptomatic but completely ambulatory",
                      "Not completely ambulatory",
                      "Not completely ambulatory",
                      "Not completely ambulatory"))


my_model <- 
    coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex * ph.ecog + inst + pat.karno * wt.loss + sex * wt.loss, 
          data = data)

my_model$xlevels
#> $sex
#> [1] "Female" "Male"  
#> 
#> $ph.ecog
#> [1] "Asymptomatic"                         
#> [2] "Symptomatic but completely ambulatory"
#> [3] "Not completely ambulatory"            
#> 
#> $inst
#> [1] "Sites 01-10" "Sites 11-20" "Sites 20-33"

colnames(model.matrix(my_model))
#>  [1] "age"                                                 
#>  [2] "sexMale"                                             
#>  [3] "ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory"        
#>  [4] "ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory"                    
#>  [5] "instSites 11-20"                                     
#>  [6] "instSites 20-33"                                     
#>  [7] "pat.karno"                                           
#>  [8] "wt.loss"                                             
#>  [9] "sexMale:ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory"
#> [10] "sexMale:ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory"            
#> [11] "pat.karno:wt.loss"                                   
#> [12] "sexMale:wt.loss"

Created on 2024-10-31 with reprex v2.1.1

I ended up writing a function that crosses all interactions and returns all term combinations. It returns the original_terms given by R, then the missing_terms that involve the reference levels of factors in interactions, then the filled_terms which is the union of the two above, and finally with_singletons, which also includes the reference terms outside interactions. As the example below shows, it seems to play nicely with interactions involving more than two variables as well.
build_missing_terms <- function(modelobj) {
    # 1. Get the names of all variables involved in each interaction. Interactions
    # have ":" in the column name, and covariates used in the interaction are
    # flagged with `1`.
    all_intx <- attr(terms(modelobj), "factors")
    all_intx <- all_intx[, grep(":", colnames(all_intx), value = FALSE)]
    all_intx <- apply(all_intx, 2, function(y) { names(y)[which(y == 1)] }, simplify = FALSE)

    # 2. Form the model term names. For Factors, it's the variable name and factor
    # label mashed together. For Numerics, it's the variable name by itself.
    custom_xlevels <-
        Map(
            function(varname) {
                vartypes <- attr(terms(modelobj), "dataClasses")

                if (vartypes[varname] == "factor") {
                    # If the variable is a factor, then paste the name together.
                    return(paste0(varname, modelobj$xlevels[[varname]]))
                } else {
                    # Otherwise, just use the variable name alone.
                    return(varname)
                }
            },

            unique(c(unlist(all_intx), names(modelobj$xlevels)))
        )

    # 3. Construct the final terms by crossing the variables used in each
    # interaction.
    constructed_terms <-
        Map(
            function(this_interaction) {
                covars_to_expand <-
                    custom_xlevels[which(names(custom_xlevels) %in% this_interaction)]

                apply(
                    expand.grid(covars_to_expand, stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
                    1,
                    function(...) {
                        paste0(..., collapse = ":")
                    }
                )
            },
            all_intx
        )

    # 4. Return the results.
    original_terms <- names(coef(modelobj))

    missing_terms <- unlist(constructed_terms, use.names = FALSE)
    missing_terms <- missing_terms[!(missing_terms %in% original_terms)]

    filled_terms <- sort(unique(c(original_terms, missing_terms)))
    sorted_filled_terms <- filled_terms[order(grepl(":", filled_terms, fixed = TRUE), filled_terms)]

    with_singletons <- sort(unique(c(unlist(custom_xlevels, use.names = FALSE), original_terms, missing_terms)))
    sorted_singletons <- with_singletons[order(grepl(":", with_singletons, fixed = TRUE), with_singletons)]

    return(list(
        original_terms  = original_terms,
        missing_terms   = sort(missing_terms),
        filled_terms    = sorted_filled_terms,
        with_singletons = sorted_singletons
    ))
}


library(survival)

data <- cancer

data$inst <-
    factor(data$inst,
           levels = c(1:33),
           labels = c(rep("Sites 01-10", 10),
                      rep("Sites 11-20", 10),
                      rep("Sites 20-33", 13)))

data$sex <-
    factor(data$sex,
           levels = 2:1,
           labels = c("Female", "Male"))

data$ph.ecog <-
    factor(data$ph.ecog,
           levels = 0:4,
           labels = c("Asymptomatic",
                      "Symptomatic but completely ambulatory",
                      "Not completely ambulatory",
                      "Not completely ambulatory",
                      "Not completely ambulatory"))

my_model <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex * ph.ecog * wt.loss + inst + pat.karno * meal.cal, data = data)

build_missing_terms(my_model)
#> $original_terms
#>  [1] "age"                                                         
#>  [2] "sexMale"                                                     
#>  [3] "ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory"                
#>  [4] "ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory"                            
#>  [5] "wt.loss"                                                     
#>  [6] "instSites 11-20"                                             
#>  [7] "instSites 20-33"                                             
#>  [8] "pat.karno"                                                   
#>  [9] "meal.cal"                                                    
#> [10] "sexMale:ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory"        
#> [11] "sexMale:ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory"                    
#> [12] "sexMale:wt.loss"                                             
#> [13] "ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory:wt.loss"        
#> [14] "ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory:wt.loss"                    
#> [15] "pat.karno:meal.cal"                                          
#> [16] "sexMale:ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory:wt.loss"
#> [17] "sexMale:ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory:wt.loss"            
#> 
#> $missing_terms
#>  [1] "ph.ecogAsymptomatic:wt.loss"                                   
#>  [2] "sexFemale:ph.ecogAsymptomatic"                                 
#>  [3] "sexFemale:ph.ecogAsymptomatic:wt.loss"                         
#>  [4] "sexFemale:ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory"                    
#>  [5] "sexFemale:ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory:wt.loss"            
#>  [6] "sexFemale:ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory"        
#>  [7] "sexFemale:ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory:wt.loss"
#>  [8] "sexFemale:wt.loss"                                             
#>  [9] "sexMale:ph.ecogAsymptomatic"                                   
#> [10] "sexMale:ph.ecogAsymptomatic:wt.loss"                           
#> 
#> $filled_terms
#>  [1] "age"                                                           
#>  [2] "instSites 11-20"                                               
#>  [3] "instSites 20-33"                                               
#>  [4] "meal.cal"                                                      
#>  [5] "pat.karno"                                                     
#>  [6] "ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory"                              
#>  [7] "ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory"                  
#>  [8] "sexMale"                                                       
#>  [9] "wt.loss"                                                       
#> [10] "pat.karno:meal.cal"                                            
#> [11] "ph.ecogAsymptomatic:wt.loss"                                   
#> [12] "ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory:wt.loss"                      
#> [13] "ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory:wt.loss"          
#> [14] "sexFemale:ph.ecogAsymptomatic"                                 
#> [15] "sexFemale:ph.ecogAsymptomatic:wt.loss"                         
#> [16] "sexFemale:ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory"                    
#> [17] "sexFemale:ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory:wt.loss"            
#> [18] "sexFemale:ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory"        
#> [19] "sexFemale:ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory:wt.loss"
#> [20] "sexFemale:wt.loss"                                             
#> [21] "sexMale:ph.ecogAsymptomatic"                                   
#> [22] "sexMale:ph.ecogAsymptomatic:wt.loss"                           
#> [23] "sexMale:ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory"                      
#> [24] "sexMale:ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory:wt.loss"              
#> [25] "sexMale:ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory"          
#> [26] "sexMale:ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory:wt.loss"  
#> [27] "sexMale:wt.loss"                                               
#> 
#> $with_singletons
#>  [1] "age"                                                           
#>  [2] "instSites 01-10"                                               
#>  [3] "instSites 11-20"                                               
#>  [4] "instSites 20-33"                                               
#>  [5] "meal.cal"                                                      
#>  [6] "pat.karno"                                                     
#>  [7] "ph.ecogAsymptomatic"                                           
#>  [8] "ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory"                              
#>  [9] "ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory"                  
#> [10] "sexFemale"                                                     
#> [11] "sexMale"                                                       
#> [12] "wt.loss"                                                       
#> [13] "pat.karno:meal.cal"                                            
#> [14] "ph.ecogAsymptomatic:wt.loss"                                   
#> [15] "ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory:wt.loss"                      
#> [16] "ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory:wt.loss"          
#> [17] "sexFemale:ph.ecogAsymptomatic"                                 
#> [18] "sexFemale:ph.ecogAsymptomatic:wt.loss"                         
#> [19] "sexFemale:ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory"                    
#> [20] "sexFemale:ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory:wt.loss"            
#> [21] "sexFemale:ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory"        
#> [22] "sexFemale:ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory:wt.loss"
#> [23] "sexFemale:wt.loss"                                             
#> [24] "sexMale:ph.ecogAsymptomatic"                                   
#> [25] "sexMale:ph.ecogAsymptomatic:wt.loss"                           
#> [26] "sexMale:ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory"                      
#> [27] "sexMale:ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory:wt.loss"              
#> [28] "sexMale:ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory"          
#> [29] "sexMale:ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory:wt.loss"  
#> [30] "sexMale:wt.loss"

Created on 2024-11-01 with reprex v2.1.1

The names of the coeeficients are set in model.matrix.default and there in a C function C_modelmatrix:
ans <- .External2(C_modelmatrix, t, data)

The names R choose, depend on the formula used and the type of contrasts encoding.
colnames(model.matrix(~ x, data = data.frame(x = C(factor(LETTERS[1:3]), "contr.treatment"))))
#  [1] "(Intercept)" "xB"          "xC"  

colnames(model.matrix(~ x - 1, data = data.frame(x = C(factor(LETTERS[1:3]), "contr.treatment"))))
#  [1] "xA" "xB" "xC"

colnames(model.matrix(~ x, data = data.frame(x = C(factor(LETTERS[1:3]), "contr.sum"))))
# [1] "(Intercept)" "x1"          "x2" 

Having said that it is not possible to get all names in any of the model outputs, b/c of the way how parameters for factors are encoded. With the default (contr.treatment) the baseline (i.e. first factor level) is encoded in the intercept and the other parameters denote the difference  between the baseline and the other levels.
For one factor you could, just for the sake of getting the names, simply remove the intercept and you would also get the name of the baseline level, but this does not work if you have more than one factor or interactions, simply because the underlying design matrix would be degenerated if you added another column for the baseline.
It helps to look at the output of model.matrix to see how R encodes factors to understand this principle.
Having said that, you can construct the reference labels from the term object like this (N.B. only a starter and not your final answer)
get_ref_levels <- function(formula, data) {
  te <- terms(formula, data = data)
  ff <- attr(te, "term.labels")
  vars <- strsplit(ff, ":", fixed = TRUE)
  vars <- Filter(\(vv)
    any(vapply(data[, vv], \(col) is.factor(col) | is.character(col), logical(1L)))
  , vars)
  vapply(vars, function(var) {
    res <- vapply(var, function(col_nm) {
      col <- data[[col_nm]]
      if (is.factor(col)) {
        paste0(col_nm, levels(col)[1L])
      } else if (is.character(col)) {
        paste0(col_nm, sort(col)[1L])
      } else {
        col_nm
      }
    }, character(1L))
    paste(res, collapse = ":")
  }, character(1L))
}


dd <- data.frame(x1 = factor(LETTERS[1:3]),
                 x2 = factor(letters[1:3]),
                 x3 = factor(paste("F", 1:3)),
                 i  = 1:3,
                 y = rnorm(3))

get_ref_levels(~ x1 * x2 * x3 * i, dd)
# [1] "x1A"             "x2a"             "x3F 1"           "x1A:x2a"         "x1A:x3F 1"       "x2a:x3F 1"       "x1A:i"           "x2a:i"           "x3F 1:i"         "x1A:x2a:x3F 1"   "x1A:x2a:i"       "x1A:x3F 1:i"    
# [13] "x2a:x3F 1:i"     "x1A:x2a:x3F 1:i"


get_ref_levels(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex * ph.ecog + inst + pat.karno * wt.loss + sex * wt.loss, data = data)
# [1] "sexFemale"                     "ph.ecogAsymptomatic"           "instSites 01-10"               "sexFemale:ph.ecogAsymptomatic" "sexFemale:wt.loss" 

However, this returns only the first level of each factor, which, in the presence of interactions, is not the full story, b/c you would need to cross each first level with all the levels and as you can imagine, this becomes more and more difficult (not impossible though). But it gives you an idea of how to proceed from here.

Very nice!  +1  But where is sexFemale:wt.loss?

Ah true, thanks fixed it.

There are two types of missing terms:

main effects of the factor variables in the model,

interactions involving factors and
(a) numeric variables (eg. sex:wtloss)
(b) other factors (eg. sex:ph.ecog)


For 1. we can use:
(ref.grps <- lapply(my_model$xlevels, '[[', 1))

$sex
[1] "Female"

$ph.ecog
[1] "Asymptomatic"

$inst
[1] "Sites 01-10"

and so the missing terms are:
paste0(names(ref.grps), ref.grps)
[1] "sexFemale"           "ph.ecogAsymptomatic" "instSites 01-10" 

For 2. we need to know which variables are included as interactions in the model. Those containing a colon : in the term.labels attribute of the terms in the model are interactions:
(interactions <- grep(":", attr(my_model$terms, "term.labels"), value=TRUE))
[1] "sex:ph.ecog"       "pat.karno:wt.loss" "sex:wt.loss" 

To separate 2a from 2b we need to know the class of the terms.
(classes <- attr(my_model$terms, "dataClasses"))
Surv(time, status)                age                sex            ph.ecog               inst          pat.karno            wt.loss 
       "nmatrix.2"          "numeric"           "factor"           "factor"           "factor"          "numeric"          "numeric" 

(fac.vars <- names(classes[classes == "factor"]))
[1] "sex"     "ph.ecog" "inst"

(num.vars <- names(classes[classes == "numeric"]))
[1] "age"       "pat.karno" "wt.loss"

We can then iterate through the list of interactions and determine how to construct the missing terms based on the class of the two terms that are interacting.
missing.terms <- list()
for(i in seq_along(interactions)) {
  v1 <- sub("(.+):.+", "\\1", interactions[i])
  v2 <- sub(".+:(.+)", "\\1", interactions[i])
  if(v1 %in% fac.vars)
    if(v2 %in% fac.vars) 
      missing.terms[[i]] <- paste(paste0(v1, ref.grps)[names(ref.grps)==v1], paste0(v2, ref.grps)[names(ref.grps)==v2], sep=":")
    else
      missing.terms[[i]] <- paste(paste0(v1, ref.grps)[names(ref.grps)==v1], v2, sep=":")
  else
    if(v2 %in% fac.vars) 
      missing.terms[[i]] <- paste(v1, paste0(v2, ref.grps)[names(ref.grps)==v2], sep=":")
    else
      missing.terms[[i]] <- NULL # both are numeric vars
}

unlist(missing.terms)
[1] "sexFemale:ph.ecogAsymptomatic" "sexFemale:wt.loss"

This assumes we are using treatment contrasts. This code may also not work for three-way interactions or higher.
Edit:
To get all of the missing names of the reference terms that are involved in interactions, use the following modified code:
missing.terms <- vector("list", length(interactions))

fac1 <- function(v) {
  paste(paste0(v[1], ref.grps)[names(ref.grps)==v[1]], v[2], sep=":")
}

fac2 <- function(v) {
  paste(paste0(v[1], ref.grps)[names(ref.grps)==v[1]], 
        paste0(v[2], unlist(my_model$xlevels[names(my_model$xlevels)==v[2]])), sep=":")
}

v <- strsplit(interactions, ":")

for(i in length(v)) {
  if(all(v[[i]] %in% fac.vars)) { 
    missing.terms[[i]] <- c(fac2(v[[i]]), fac2(rev(v[[i]])))
  } else if(any(v[[i]] %in% fac.vars)) {
    missing.terms[[i]] <- fac1(v[[i]])
  }
}

unlist(missing.terms)


[1] "sexFemale:ph.ecogAsymptomatic"                         
[2] "sexFemale:ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory"
[3] "sexFemale:ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory"            
[4] "ph.ecogAsymptomatic:sexFemale"                         
[5] "ph.ecogAsymptomatic:sexMale"                           
[6] "sexFemale:wt.loss"


Like my solution this would miss sexFemale:ph.ecogSymptomatic but completely ambulatory and sexFemale:ph.ecogNot completely ambulatory

@thothal Actually, those terms are not "missing" in the sense that they are not used in the comparisons for sex:ph.ecog.

well the OP wants them nonetheless.  See his example with countryAustralia:educGrade school, countryAustralia:educHigh school, countryAustralia:educUniversity
